# Dotnetcore Project to have version controlled pre-commit / pre-push hooks

Tags: git, .net-core, nuke-build

I am coming from NodeJS world where I can easily add `pre-commit` and `pre-push` hooks with the husky or many other libraries.

Is there any way/library that can do the same for `dotnetcore`?

If not can Nukebuild copy files to `../.git/hooks` folder (based on the OS)?
I am looking for something like

```
public Targets Hook => _ => _
            .Description("Setup Hooks")
            .Executes(() => {
               // checks the os
               // copy file to ../.git/hooks based on the os
            });
```

Comment: There's a slack workspace for nuke at https://slofile.com/slack/nukebuildnet

Comment: I have never sever seen a .NET Library that simplifies install/removal of git hooks like husky can.

Answer (score 0):

You can check on which operating system you're on using `EnvironmentInfo.IsWin`, `IsUnix`, `IsOsx`.